# Choices for thread safe get/clear operations to Map in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I have a multithreaded application in which I create a Singleton object that is used across threads to refer to get the current user mapping.

There are 3 methods in my class
init - Loads initial map state. Creates a periodic thread that checks if mapping needs to be loaded again.

get - Reads current value

refresh - Based on certain conditions reload all the map entries again

```
@Singleton
class MyClass {

    Map<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct // On App start
    void init() {
        // Loads the HashMap with initial contents
        loadMap(); 

        createRefreshTask(2);
    }

    public Optional<String> map(String username) {
       // Checks map to get value for a username
       return Optional.OfNullable(map.get(username));
    }

    private void createRefreshTask(int refreshIntervalMins) {
        ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            refresh();
        }, 0, refreshIntervalMins, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    void refresh() {
       // Conditionally clear and reload all the map entries again
       if (needsRefresh()) {
           map.clear();
           loadMap();
       } 
    } 
}
```

As I understand the get is unlocked with ConcurrentHashMap. Does that mean I will serve no entries during a refresh since the old map entries have been cleared during refresh? Should I use a Synchronized Map in that case, or use primitives like Semaphore here? I am assuming the refresh are going to be infrequent so I am wondering if I have a way to not slow down get operations. What would be a good choice to use here?

Comment: `clear` and `loadMap` together are not atomic. So, if one thread clears the map, another thread might get empty `Optional`s before the map is filled again.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is something like a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. You need to keep the reads fast and only lock if you need to refresh the map.

Comment: Yes, even if I make refresh synchronized there would be possibility that get returns empty ```Optional```. So should I use some Semaphore here so that get tries to acquire it before anything else it does?

Comment: For your specific use case (i.e. writing only within the refresh method), you don't even need a `ConcurrentHashMap`. You just need read and write locks. :)

Comment: So that writing is exclusive (one thread) and multiple threads can read at the same time.

Comment: The other option: using a `ConcurrentHashMap` but without clearing it. Only updating and removing outdated values.

Comment: 1. I have no means to find outdated values. I have the use case to delete old entries too as some users may have lost being mapped. I won't catch it unless I traverse whole Map again. 2. So as I understand ConcurrentHashMap only helps with mulitiple writers and consistent values. But even then the readers might get stale values since get is unlocked on the internal Map segment. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, a `ConcurrentHashMap` only locks the segments which are being written in. I don't really know what you want to achieve, but it depends on the consistency level. If you can't accept any stale values at all, you need to check the staleness for every read. But that has a huge performance penalty.

Comment: @Michael segments only exist prior to Java 8. Since then, there are no segments, hence, there’s not even locking of segments. But anyway, the definition of staleness is unclear in this context anyway. So, a value might be perfectly ok 1:59 after the last update, but “stale” after 2:00? Doesn’t make much sense to me.